# Why is x-- a valid ruby statement but it doesn't do anything?

Tags: ruby, operators, comparison-operators

I know ruby doesn't support integer increment `x++` or decrement `x--` as C does. But when I use it, it doesn't do anything and doesn't throw an error either. Why?

Edit:

Sorry the code I actually found was using `--x`, which is slightly different, but the question remains: Why?

```rb
x = 10
while --x > 0
  y = x
end
```

Comment: Note that `x++` and `x==` exhibit the same behavior.

Comment: Did the code that contained this report any *other* errors?  Can you show the code that contains `x--` but does not complain about it?

Comment: Sorry the code I actually found was using `--x`, see my edit above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Ruby, [operators are methods](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_operators.htm). --x, x++, x==, etc all can do wildly different things. `--` and `++` are not themselves valid operators. They are combinations of operators.

In the case of your provided code, `--x` is the same as `-(-x)`.

If `x == 5`, then `-x == -5` and `--x == 5`.

`---x` would be `-(-(-x))`, and so on.

Similarly, `x--` alone on a line is technically valid, depending on what the next line of code contains.

For example, the following method is valid:

```
  def foo
    x = 1
    y = 10
    x--
    y
  end
```

The last two lines of that method get interpreted as `x - (-y)` which calculates to `1 - (-10)`.

The result doesn't get assigned to any value, so the `x--` line would appear to do nothing and the function would just return the result: 11.

You could even have `nil` on the last line of the function instead of `y`, and you wouldn't get a syntax error, but you would get a runtime error when the function is called. The error you would receive from `x--nil` is:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `-@' for nil:NilClass
```

That means that `-nil` is invalid since `NilClass` does not define the method `-@`. The `@` indicates that `-` works as a [unary operator](http://www.rubyinside.com/rubys-unary-operators-and-how-to-redefine-their-functionality-5610.html). Another way to express `--x` by invoking the unary operators manually is `x.-@.-@`

`x--` just on its own is not valid. It requires a Numeric object to follow it (or any object which implemented `-@`). That object can be on the next line. `x==` would work the same way.

Answer (score 0):

> But when I use it, it doesn't do anything and doesn't throw an error either.

It does:

```sh
ruby -ce 'x--'
# -e:1: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input
```

`x--` is not valid Ruby syntax.

Comment: Clearly @eikes and I have not seen this error; perhaps due to our having this line being in a file and not passed as a command line argument?

Comment: The Ruby syntax is the Ruby syntax, it doesn't matter where it comes from. If it is not legal Ruby syntax, it is not legal Ruby syntax: `echo 'x--' > test.rb; ruby -c test.rb # test.rb:1: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input`

Comment: Sorry the code I actually found was using `--x`, see my edit above